# jquery : How to filter elements which have more than a specific number of children?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i select elements which have more than a number of children?

I have something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>foo<li>
    <li>foo<li>
    <li>foo<li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>foo<li>
    <li>foo<li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>foo<li>
    <li>foo<li>
    <li>foo<li>
</ul>
```

and i am using somthing like this right now:

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    if ($(this).children().length > 2) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

I want to know if there is a better way for selecting by number of children?

or any better way to do this?

Comment: No, but you need to count the children of the `<ul>`, not the `<ul>` itself.

Comment: I think it should be `$(this).find('li').length > 2`

Comment: I guess you can loop through the children?

Comment: what about http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is at least a shorter way

```
$('ul:has(li:eq(2))')
```

For immediate children only, if that's an issue, you can do

```
$('ul:has( > li:eq(2))')
```

selects any UL with 3 or more children (eq is zero based)

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/A6p7p/3/)

Comment: This is broken if grand-children elements match the selector http://jsfiddle.net/A6p7p/2/

Comment: @TCHdvlp - That's not part of the question, but it's an easy fix

Comment: Yep, I assume this is what he's looking for. You can write the 2 solutions. EDIT; got my +1 for this complete answer.

Comment: Thanx. that was actually what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('li').length > 2) {
     alert('hi');
    }
});
```

Use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to count number of children available for ul.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/7GX9F/1/

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var listsWithMoreChildren = $('ul').filter(function( index ) {
    return $(this).children().length > 2;
});
listsWithMoreChildren.css('background-color', '#ff0');
```

For more information on the filter function, please read the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0;

$('ul').each(function (index, ele) {
    if ($(this).children().length > 0) i++;
})

alert('Total UL with children LI : ' + i);
```

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/nraina/GckZL/